# Error: The setter 'pressed' isn't defined for the class '_HomeState'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

So, I'm trying to create a style for when the person clicks the button, It will change its color, I have a separate function in which creates the buttons, so I call this functions to create them. But when I passed a bool variable, the main function, doesn't seem to accept that variable (bool). It stays highlighted in red and gives me this The setter `pressed` isn't defined for the class `_HomeState`
Here is the create button function:

```
class CustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
// define this parameters as you will need them
final Function onPressed;
final IconData icon;
final String text;
final String text2;

// define a constructor for the class custom button
CustomButton({this.onPressed, this.icon, this.text, this.text2});

@override
_CustomButtonState createState() => _CustomButtonState();
}

class _CustomButtonState extends State<CustomButton> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
  child: SizedBox(
    width: 90.0,
    height: 90.0,
    child: RaisedButton(
      // remove the default padding the raised button has
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      onPressed: () {},
      color: Colors.grey,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, right: 25, bottom: 10),
                child: Icon(
                  widget.icon,
                  size: 35,
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0),
                child: new Text(
                  widget.text,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 17),
            child: Text(
              widget.text2,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Here is the main function when I call the CustomButton():

```
CustomButton(
          icon: Icons.lightbulb_outline,
          text: 'On',
          text2: 'Lâmpada 1\nSchuma',
          pressed: false,
         style: pressed ?                                            
         TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0) :
          TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0),
          onPressed: () => (){
          setState(() {
          pressed = !pressed; <- THis stay highlighted in red
   });
},
),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you are trying to assign **pressed** value to pressed but it is not define in _HomeState class.

In _HomeState class their is no variable pressed.

Update:

```
class CustomButton extends StatefulWidget {
// define this parameters as you will need them
  final Function onPressed;
  final IconData icon;
  final String text;
  final String text2;
  final bool pressed;
  final TextStyle style;

// define a constructor for the class custom button
  CustomButton(
      {this.onPressed,
      this.icon,
      this.text,
      this.text2,
      this.pressed,
      this.style});

  @override
  _CustomButtonState createState() => _CustomButtonState();
}

class _CustomButtonState extends State<CustomButton> {
  bool btn = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipRRect(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      child: SizedBox(
        width: 90.0,
        height: 90.0,
        child: RaisedButton(
          // remove the default padding the raised button has
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              btn = !btn;
            });
          },
          color: btn ? Colors.grey : Colors.amber,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, right: 25, bottom: 10),
                    child: Icon(
                      widget.icon,
                      size: 35,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 20, left: 0),
                    child: new Text(
                      widget.text,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 17),
                child: Text(
                  widget.text2,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but how can I solve it, because I have on function that creates the button, and another that is the "main one"

Comment: just pass true or false.

Comment: I tried that mate, but I will have to set 1 variable inside each function, an then it wont change the state at all

Comment: you can make CustomButton class stateful and and oppressed event change color accordingly using setState.

Comment: @NiltonSchumacherF i updated my code. not on click you can see colour is changing of background in same way you can change style.

Comment: Great worked like a charm, can I use this to change, color style and backgroung style too?

Comment: yes definitely. Accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: for the style, will I have to do it like this? style: btn ? TextStyle(color: Colors.white) : TextStyle(color: Colors.black),

Answer (score 1):

You have a class `_HomeState` in which you use your `CustomButton`, and you are trying to assign value `pressed` to that button, but this property doesn't exist in `_HomeState`. There are couple of potential issues:

1. You are using `pressed` instead of `widget.pressed`
2. You are using `pressed` instead of `_pressed`
3. You did not define `pressed` as a property of `_HomeState` at all and you need to first define it

EDIT:

In order to alter button state on pressed you need to do it inside your button class, not in a parent widget. This is the simplest possible example with just changing color:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyButton extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _MyButtonState();
}

class _MyButtonState extends State<MyButton> {
  bool _pressed = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RaisedButton(
        color: _pressed ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.blueAccent,
        child: Text('Change color'),
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            _pressed = !_pressed;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: When pressed I have to call the Style: pressed. When I put it into the CustomButton, it wont work.

Comment: If your goal is to change styling on press, you are approaching this the wrong way. You need to create StatefulWidget for the Button class and keep this property private to the button class.

Comment: I have made that right now, gonna update the question too, but should i add the style: pressed ?... in which function, the main or the CustomButton?

Comment: You need 2 styles pressed and idle inside the button. And you alter them once your button registers change on press.

Comment: Could you give me a Code preview just so I can try, and set your comment as right

Comment: I just edited my initial post with an example code for button that changes color on pressed. You can play around with button properties and change any of them as you like the same way like background is changing here.

Comment: Great worked like a charm, can I use this to change, color style and backgroung style too?

Comment: Yes, button offers a variety of properties to change a lot of stuff like shadows, corner radius, colors, borders, text, image, etc....